# Метод splice() JS

Tags: javascript

let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].splice(1, 2); // результат [2, 3]

let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let sub = arr.splice(1, 2); // результат [1, 4, 5]

Почему разный результат? Применяется ведь тот-же метод?!

Comment: брехня. и там и там будет 2,3

Comment: Может вы путаете `slice` и `splice`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Читаем доки https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

> Возвращаемое значение Массив, содержащий удалённые элементы.

Если вы смотрите в первом примере на `arr`, а во втором на `sub`, то увидите **одинаковый** результат.

Если и там и там смотрите на `arr`, то логично, что результат разный., потому что в первом случае в `arr`  складывается возвращаемый результат, а во втором в `arr` хранится то, что **не вырезали**, так как над ним делали операции, а результат вернули в `sub`

---

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].splice(1, 2); 
console.log(arr);

arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let sub = arr.splice(1, 2);
console.log(sub); // Результат одинаковый и по-другому быть не может

//--------------------------------

arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].splice(1, 2); 
console.log(arr);

arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
sub = arr.splice(1, 2);
console.log(arr); // Результат разный, потому что результат в #1 складывается в arr, а в #2 в sub, а сама операция производится с arr и никак не перезаписывается чем либо ещё
```

Comment: С первым вопросом разобрался! Почему здесь let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].splice(3, 0, 'a', 'b', 'c'); пустой массив в консоли, а если разделить строки тогда все в порядке?

Comment: @Дмитрий Если текущий ответ помог - жмякаем галочку. Если возник другой вопрос - оформляем новый